# Android Facebook SDK lowers app performance

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am using Facebook SDK for my android app. I am facing scroll lags and performance issues all over the app. Removing the sdk removes all the issues. But i intend to use the sdk for analytics purpose. Is there anything that has to be added with addition to sdk. Any insight is helpful.

I tried just adding the analytics implementation in gradle but still facing the same issues

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.41.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.41.0'

Answer (score 13):

I have realized that the FB auto logging causes the lag. Specially when we put the app to background then bring it back to foreground for several times.

To disable the auto logging, add these to your manifest:

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>
```

ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#auto-events

I have no idea how and how can this feature make this serious problem..

Comment: Then you can log the events your self to serve your statistic.

Comment: Fascinating degenerates. Thank you!

Comment: How about if we need the auto-log-event feature? Any other solution?

Comment: Dang, I was trying to find this culprit FOR MONTHS! Thank you!