# Activity does not scroll smoothly when resume multiple times

Tags: java, android

My android application has a serious problem, it is when activity resumes multiple times (about 10 times), the activity will become lag when scroll. If I start a new activity, the new one works smoothly, but if I make it resume about 10 times, it will also become lag as the first one. I have tried with simple UI, just a `ScrollView` and a few `TextView`s. Below is my class implementation:

```
public class TestLagActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //make activity resume when press back button 
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
            onResume();
    }
}
```

Does anyone meet a case like that? Could you suggest me a few reasons which can lead to such a problem? If you need more code, please let me know and I will provide them to you.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
When I press back button to make activity resume (see onBackPressed() method above), the activity lag, and logcat showed:

```
2020-03-13 21:53:42.731 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.279 22255-22255/com.mypackagename.dev D/KeyEvent: obtain, mHwFlags=1768911460
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.286 22255-22255/com.mypackagename.dev D/KeyEvent: obtain, mHwFlags=1768911460
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.290 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148835
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.307 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connecting to remote service
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.311 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148846
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.328 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.328 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148855
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.345 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.346 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148867
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.362 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.363 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148876
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.379 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.380 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148887
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.397 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.397 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148896
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.413 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.414 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148907
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.427 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.428 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148921
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.432 22255-22290/com.mypackagename.dev I/zygote64: Starting profile saver IsSaveProfileNow end.
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.440 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.441 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148930
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.453 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.454 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 16148942
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.466 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.467 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev D/FA: Connected to remote service
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.470 22255-22314/com.mypackagename.dev V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 11
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.549 22255-22262/com.mypackagename.dev I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=251KB, data=151KB
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.549 22255-22262/com.mypackagename.dev I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=251KB, data=151KB
        2020-03-13 21:53:44.549 22255-22262/com.mypackagename.dev I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
```

**UPDATE 2:** xml file for the activity:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/verify" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/verify" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/verify" />

    <!--Other TextViews-->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/verify" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/verify" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE 3:** Dependances used in project.

```
implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
implementation "com.rizlee.view:rangeseekbar:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.2'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.11.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.39.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.2'
implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1.2'
implementation(name:'HERE-sdk-lite', ext:'aar')
implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:4.4.0'
```

Comment: Please add source code of your activity to your comment.

Comment: @Thank for your attention, As i mentioned above, the activities extend from AppCompatActivity and i just override onCreate() method. In this method, I just setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui), I didn't declare any instance field inside the activity

Comment: Why are you trying to call onResume 10 (actually 11) times?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Because in my app, activities become lag when resume about 5 - 10 times. Therefor, I write this function to perform such situation for quicker testing.

Comment: But your `onResume` seems empty, so that is rather odd?

Comment: Yes, it's a strange question to me! I don't know why, I tried to call `onStart()` multiple times but the app still works normally, lag only appears when one activity resume multiple times.

Comment: In my app, I use FirebaseCrashlytics, could FirebaseCrashlytics cause the issue?

Comment: @TaQuangTu check ur memory footprint and also verify if UI thread is skipping frames

Comment: @SarthakMittal Yes, memory increase and UI skip frames when i scroll layout after multiple times of resume.

Comment: @TaQuangTu something fishy is surely happening, It feels like you are doing some heavy operations on UI thread and those operations are getting triggered by the lifecycle events

Comment: @SarthakMittal Activity above is very clear. The issue also appears when i create a new blank activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week, I find out `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.11.0'` make activities in my app become lag after resume. I solve it by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439019/8531215)